# "Requested URI is invalid" during upload with FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I trying upload file to a directory on a FTP server. I used this method with `FtpWebRequest`.
I would like to upload one file to a home directory for this user, but I always get the following error message:

> The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.

What can be problem? I tried use passive mode off, but it still the same.

```
static void FtpUpload()
{


    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://12.22.44.45");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.UsePassive = false;

    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("pokus", "password");

    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(path);
    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

    response.Close();

}
```

Comment: The error suggests that there is no ftp server sitting on 12.22.44.45 willing to accept the credentials of pokus and password (whatever the real info is). Have you attempted to ftp to this server outside of code using these settings/credentials?

Comment: Can you tell us where you get the error message?  That is, what statement causes the error?

Answer (score 51):

If you want to upload something, you'll [have to provide the FTPClient with a filename](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/0ba8d3b4-e7da-4130-83bb-db1aa0c974f8).

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://12.22.44.45/myNewFile.dat");
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which is a higher level abstraction and works with HTTP and FTP and has much simpler API and performance-wise pretty the same (uses the same API).

Here is [upload data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a.aspx).